# Cast or convert a list of String to a user defined object in Scala

Tags: scala, casting, case-class

Let say I have a list of strings:

```
val myList: List[String] = List("A", "B", "C")
```

Is there a way to convert/cast this list to a user defined Object without hardcoding, something along the lines of:

```
case class MyClass(name1: String, name2: String, name3: String)
val result: MyClass = myList.asInstanceOf[MyClass]
```

Comment: you will get a class cast exception if you do it

Comment: why do you have to type cast .. what is the purpose

Comment: `case class MyClass(names: List[String])` and pass the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val result: MyClass = myList match {
  case name1 :: name2 :: name3 :: Nil => MyClass(name1, name2, name3)
  case _ => MyClass("", "", "") // default case, if list has less than 3 strings
}
```

Comment: Should have `Nil` not `_` so it matches exactly 3 strings in the `List`

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Fixed!